# Hosting SSL tunneled OpenVPN and HTTPS on the same server at the same 443 port

Tags: ssl, openvpn, haproxy, stunnel

Is there a way to host a SSL-tunneled (using stunnel) OpenVPN server and a regular Apache HTTPS server on the same server using HAProxy? It seems that by using stunnel, the format of the packets should all the way be the same. Is there any ways to make a difference between the two kinds of packets (which is not detectable by DPI) for the HAProxy to sort them out? I tried to use different domain names for the HTTPS server and the OpenVPN Server (though they point to the same IP address) but seems it doesn't work because OpenVPN does not use SNI.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure, but OpenVPN does support connecting through an http proxy.  Perhaps you could run the OpenVPN server behind and somehow get your box to proxy for OpenVPN?

Comment: Also related: https://serverfault.com/questions/382916/openvpn-port-sharing-can-traffic-be-distinguished-from-https and https://serverfault.com/questions/113680/route-specific-http-requests-through-pfsense-openvpn